# Facebook and WordPress

Tags: login, facebook

Is there a way to create a login/register with facebook and facebook comments on my wordpress site without using plugins?

Some sort of a guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Facebook Comments for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/) plugin or the [Disqus Comment System](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/), which allows comment login using Google, Twitter, Facebook, or OpenID accounts, and is totally import/export compatible with WP comments.

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange question. Plugins are there only to extend WordPress functionality. If you have some problems in using plugins Why not you copy the whole plugin code and paste it in your theme files?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.... without writing a plugin's worth of code.

Why not use a plugin like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/)?